GraphQL and Zeenea
I'm trying to get all the items and definitions from glossaries in the Data Governance Platform Zeenea.. In the documentation, it states that it uses GraphQL in their API. Being not familiar with this, i started investigating, but, coming to a hold at the second step of the journey. The items in the Business_Glossary are Businessterms, and on the properties (assumption) is the definition. Somehow, I cannot get the details of a glossary via the API and I'm getting a bit desperate, even though documentation on the matter (https://docs.zeenea.com/) is available.
def run_graphql_query(query, variables):
    url = 'URL'  

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-APP-ID': 'ID',
        'X-API-KEY': 'KEY'
    }

    data = {
        'query': query,
        'variables': variables
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Query failed with status code {response.status_code}: {response.text}")


def get_glossaries():
   # Variabelen voor de query
    query_variables = {
        "type": "Business_Glossary",
    }

    # De GraphQL-query
    graphql_query = """
    query Items(
      $type: ItemType!
    ) {
      items(
        type: $type
      ) {
        nodes {
          id
          type
          key
          name
      }
    }
    }    
    """

   
    result = run_graphql_query(graphql_query, query_variables) 

    output = []

    items = result['data']['items']['nodes']  # LIST
    print(items)
    for item in items:
        output.append({'id': item['id'], 'name': item['name']})
    return output

This gets the glossaries as expected. Then, I want to use the retrieved GlossaryID (or ID) to get all the items in this glossary, but I get stuck:
def get_glossary_items(glossary_id):
    # Variables for the query
    query_variables = {
        "glossaryId": glossary_id
    }

    
    graphql_query = """
    query ItemsInGlossary($glossaryId: ID!) {
      item(ref: {id: $glossaryId}) {
        ... on Business_Glossary {
          items {
            nodes {
              id
              type
              key
              name
              description {
                content
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    """

    return run_graphql_query(graphql_query, query_variables)

glossary_items = get_glossary_items(business_glossary_id)
print(glossary_items)

I get an error:

{'errors': [{'message': "Syntax Error: Invalid value for ItemReference: '[object Object]'", 'locations': [{'line': 3, 'column': 17}]}, {'message': 'Unknown type "Business_Glossary".', 'locations': [{'line': 4, 'column': 16}]}]}

And I have no idea what next action I can take. Anyone here a wizard on graphQL API's?
